# couchdb dead but pid file exists

Tags: linux, centos, couchdb, rpm, yum

I have a Centos 6.4 x64 server with epel repo enabled. I installed couchdb via the yum package manager (version 1.0.4) with no errors. I edited the `/etc/couchdb/local.ini` file with my port (default `5984`) and server ip address. Whenever I run the `service couchdb start`, it returns the ok message:

> Starting couchdb:                                          [  OK  ]

However, if I run a `service couchdb status` right after, I get this:

> couchdb dead but pid file exists

and, of course, the server does not work.

The weird part is that `service couchdb start` always returns the success message, although the server never actually runs. Also, there is no log files created at all by couchdb (my `/var/log/couchdb/` folder is empty - doubled checked couchdb configuration files for the path).

When I delete the `/var/run/subsys/couchdb.pid` file, service shows couchdb as not started, and when I try to restart couchdb (`service couchdb start`), I get the success message again and so on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that when I run `couchdb` it works fine (giving me only this warning `warning: "TODO: max is currently unsupported"`), so it is just the service that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are so many instances running for couchdb you have to kill each and every and then restart the servcie. Hope it works fine.

Comment: There weren't any instances of couchdb were running. I had to compile couchdb from source (not the best solution, but the server had to be fixed asap) to make it run.